# How can I access PostgREST from an external PC?

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

How can I configure PostgREST to process requests from an external PC?

If I make a request from the computer on which it is running. All work. With a remote database running.
But when I run it on RDP on the server and try to contact. Nothing happens.

Specify the IP address of the server and port in the parameters. I did not bring any successes.

```
server-host = "* 4"
server-port = 3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my configuration for `server-host` and `server-port` when I start postgres in a digitalocean or linode machine:

```
server-host = "0.0.0.0"
server-port = "80"
```